# How does Sqoop map csv file column to column of my sql table

Tags: mysql, csv, sqoop

how does Sqoop mapped  import csv file to my sql table's column ?  I just ran below import and export sqoop command and it work properly but not sure how Sqoop mapped the imported result into my sql table column's ? I have CSV file created manually which I want to export to my sql so need a way to specify csv file & column mapping ..

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mydb \
--username myuser \
--password mypassword \
--query 'SELECT MARS_ID , MARKET_ID , USERROLE_ID , LEADER_MARS_ID , CREATED_TIME , CREATED_USER , LST_UPDTD_TIME , LST_UPDTD_USER FROM USERS_TEST u WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
-m 1 \
--target-dir /idn/home/data/user
```

Deleted record from my sql database and run the below export command which inserted data back into table .

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mydb \
--table USERS_TEST \
--export-dir /idn/home/data/user \
--username myuser \
--password mypassword \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize **--input-fields-terminated-by** and **--columns** parameters to control the structure of the data to be exported back to RDBMS through Sqoop.

I would recommend you to refer the [sqoop user guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal) for more information.